# How to properly type a higher order function

Tags: typescript

I have a higher order function, for example in vanilla JS like this:

```
function log(fn) {
  return (...args) => {
    console.log("Calling", fn.name);
    return fn(...args);
  }
}
```

And used like this:

```
let name;
const setName = log((newName) => {
   name = newName;
});
setName("Hello"); // output "Calling setName"
```

How can I properly type this in TS such that `setName` has the correct function signature? Meaning:

```
setName("hello") // OK
setName() // Error, missing arg
setName(123) // Error, number not string
```

What I've come up with so far is:

```
function log<F extends Function>(fn: F): F {
  return (...args: any[]) => {
    console.log("Calling", fn.name);
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

let name;
const setName = log((newName: string) => {
  name = newName;
});
```

Which works the way I want (I get argument type checking on `setName`) but I get a compile error on the `log` function return:

> Error: TS2322:Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'F'.

Even if I use `<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>` I get the same error. Basically, I don't know how to make the returned function satisfy the generic type `F`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## With a function overload

[Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) can be used. It is a way to separate the definition from the implementation:

```
function log<F extends Function>(fn: F): F
function log(fn: Function) {
    return (...args) => {
        console.log("Calling", fn.name);
        return fn(...args);
    }
}
```

I like the overload version because it helps to produce TypeScript definitions when the module is distributed as a precompiled NPM package.

## With a type assertion `as F`

The type `Function` is too wide. Your wrapped function must be a subtype of: `(...args: any[]) => any`.

You can use `as F` in order to say to TypeScript to be confident to the returned function:

```
function log<F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: F): F {
    return ((...args: any[]) => {
        console.log("Calling", fn.name);
        return fn(...args);
    }) as F
}
```

## With a type assertion `as any`

Same implementation but we can use `Function` and `as any` instead of `(...args: any[]) => any` and `as F` (see the Louis's answer).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of using function overloads like this.

Comment: I edited with the idea of the other contributor. The type `Function` is too wide. Your wrapped function must be of type: `(...args: any[]) => any`.

Comment: Interesting, I tried `F extends (...args: any[]) => any` with my original code and it still didn't allow me to return even with that exact signature for some reason, and `as F` didn't work with `F extends Function`. Honestly, I don't understand why this is different, but it works.

Comment: My idea was: `Function` are objects, they can have extra members. For example, a function interface: `interface setNameFn { (data: string): void; otherMember: string; }`. Your wrapper doesn't implement this case, and I wanted to provide a way for the compiler to control this case. But, after some tests, it seems that `log` accepts functions of type `setNameFn`. So, the better choice is maybe the easiest to read, with `Function` and `as any` instead of `(...args: any[]) => any` and `as F`.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward modification you can make is to force the type of your return value to `any`:

```
function log<F extends Function>(fn: F): F {
  return ((...args: any[]) => {
    console.log("Calling", fn.name);
    return fn(...args);
  }) as any;
}
```

This compiles file, and doing this, your `setName` function will have the same signature as what you pass to `log`.

Comment: Thanks, I found this works but I don't like using `as any`... also, why doesn't `as Function` work?

Comment: Using `as any` is not any worse than using `as F` as in the other answer. Either way, you are telling the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing". `as Function` cannot work because `F` is determined by the parameter you are passing. to `log`. If `F` is an extension of `Function` assigning an object of type `F` to a variable that can take objects of type `Function` is perfectly fine, but assigning an object of type `Function` to a variable that can take objects of type `F` is not okay. You are essentially trying to do the latter if you use `as Function` instead of `as any`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Basically it's because you can't assign a base-type to a sub-type.